# How to hide templates from the main page when working with backbone

Tags: html, backbone.js

I have a home JSP Page. I have a home template jsp page.
Now i include my template jsp page inside the home jsp so the template are accessible for backbone code.

Is it possible i don't have to include the template jsp page in home page and i can define my template some other place but still accessible from backbone code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create folder 'template' in your project and make a different html file in this folder for each template. You load the temlpate code in memory when you bootstrap your application. You can still choose to have all templates in one file. I prefer not to for readability.

Have a look at [this article](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/). It's a clean way to organize your templates and very mainainable!